# What is the difference between httpd_read_user_content and httpd_enable_homedirs?

Tags: apache-2.2, selinux

The apache module of SELinux has two similar boolean parameters: `httpd_read_user_content` and `httpd_enable_homedirs`.

Man page says the former allows httpd to read *user content* and the latter allow httpd to read *home directories*.

What is the difference between them?

Which parameter should I set true if I want to allow httpd to read files on `/home/foo` directory?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`httpd_read_user_content` allows any confined web server to read files in user home directories in `/home`.

`httpd_enable_homedirs` allows Apache to use its `UserDir` directive (i.e. URLs that look like `http://www.example.com/~username/`).

If you are just mapping domain names to users' directories, it should be sufficient to enable the first one, `httpd_read_user_content`, but if you want to use Apache user directories, you should enable both.

Answer (score 3):

After doing some research myself, I investigated the differences between them using `sesearch` command:

```
$ sesearch --allow -s httpd_t -b httpd_read_user_content
Found 5 semantic av rules:
   allow httpd_t user_home_dir_t : dir { ioctl read getattr lock search open } ; 
   allow httpd_t user_home_t : file { ioctl read getattr lock open } ; 
   allow httpd_t user_home_t : dir { ioctl read getattr lock search open } ; 
   allow httpd_t home_root_t : dir { getattr search open } ; 
   allow httpd_t home_root_t : lnk_file { read getattr } ;
$ sesearch --allow -s httpd_t -b httpd_enable_homedirs
Found 15 semantic av rules:
   allow httpd_t user_home_dir_t : dir { ioctl read getattr lock search open } ; 
   allow httpd_t user_home_dir_t : lnk_file { read getattr } ; 
   allow httpd_t autofs_t : dir { ioctl read getattr lock search open } ; 
   allow httpd_t cifs_t : file { ioctl read getattr lock open } ; 
   allow httpd_t cifs_t : dir { ioctl read getattr lock search open } ; 
   allow httpd_t cifs_t : lnk_file { read getattr } ; 
   allow httpd_t nfs_t : file { ioctl read getattr lock open } ; 
   allow httpd_t nfs_t : dir { ioctl read getattr lock search open } ; 
   allow httpd_t nfs_t : lnk_file { read getattr } ; 
   allow httpd_t user_home_t : file { ioctl read getattr lock open } ; 
   allow httpd_t user_home_t : dir { ioctl read getattr lock search open } ; 
   allow httpd_t user_home_type : dir { getattr search open } ; 
   allow httpd_t user_home_type : lnk_file { read getattr } ; 
   allow httpd_t home_root_t : dir { ioctl read getattr lock search open } ; 
   allow httpd_t home_root_t : lnk_file { read getattr } ;
```

All rules of the `http_read_user_content` are included in the `httpd_t -b httpd_enable_homedirs`. That is, the scope of the latter is wider than the former.

As Michael said correctly, we should enable only the first one if we just want to place the document root on the home directory of a user.