# selinux settings for script run by apache to pull git repo

Tags: apache-2.4, selinux, gitlab

I have a web server running apache under CentOS which as selinux enabled. I have a separate server which has gitlab running.

I'm trying to create a workflow using gitlab's web hooks so that when code is pushed to git, gitlab will request a page on my production server which will then pull the latest version of the code.

The script is all running fine, but selinux is not allowing `git pull` to run from the script. It fails with exit code 128.

**Simplified PHP script**

```
<?php 
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
exec('./.hooks/received-push.sh ' . $data->repository->url);
```

**Simplified bash script**

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$#" -ne 1]; then
  echo "Repo URL must be provided"
fi
GIT=/usr/local/bin/git

TMP=mktemp
cd $TMP
$GIT clone $1 || echo "git clone failed with exit code $?"
```

I have already discovered that `httpd_can_network_connect` was set to off, so I've turned that on. If I disable selinux, everything works fine, so I know that there is something getting in the way here. The script works fine when run manually.

Looking at audit.log, I see this line appear when git clone is run (put in multiple lines here for readability)

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1420243675.063:1041): avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=4376 comm="ssh" name="apache" dev=dm-2 ino=133906 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1420243675.063:1041): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=no exit=-13 a0=7fff9e4e4380 a1=0 a2=1b6 a3=0 items=0 ppid=4375 pid=4376 auid=4294967295 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="ssh" exe="/usr/bin/ssh" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 key=(null)
```

Are there any other selinux booleans which I can set to allow httpd to use ssh? Can I modify the file tags to enable it to run ssh?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running the AVC through `audit2allow` gives the following notice:

```
#!!!! This avc can be allowed using one of the these booleans:
#     httpd_read_user_content, httpd_enable_homedirs
```

In this case, `httpd_read_user_content` will be [the appropriate one to use](https://serverfault.com/q/461504/126632).

---

Note that it's a good idea to set SELinux to *permissive* so that you can collect all of the AVCs at once. This way you generally need to go through one iteration of setting booleans and possibly a custom policy, rather than several iterations.

Comment: That's gotten rid of that AVC but I see that there are others now. I'll take a look in more detail with `audit2allow` - I was unaware of that tool, thanks!