# Unable to set AJXP_DATA_PATH variable for Pydio in CentOS

Tags: centos, nginx, permissions, php-fpm, centos7

I'm trying to launch Pydio on my CentOS 7 server with Nginx. I get to a point where everything is working, I mean I get a Pydio Error, it is generated by Pydio.

> Impossible write into the AJXP_DATA_PATH folder: Make sure to grant write access to this folder for your webserver!

I've checked. I have AJXP_DATA_PATH pointing to /home/pydio and the nginx user have read/write permissions. That user is running nginx worker processes and php-fpm.

So, why it says I do not have write permission to the data folder if I have?

I've searched on google and there is only one type of solutions there, set write permissions, but I have set them.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably hitting an [SELinux](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/SELinux_Users_and_Administrators_Guide/) restriction: by default web server processes are not allowed to access anything in user home directories.

There are two ways to resolve this:

1. (Preferred) Relocate the web application to a directory permitted by SELinux, such as a subdirectory of `/srv/www` (e.g. `/srv/www/pydio`). Do this if your web application may need to *write* data to the filesystem, as you can then [mark the writable directories](https://serverfault.com/q/626610/126632) with [`semanage fcontext`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/SELinux_Users_and_Administrators_Guide/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files.html#sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files-Persistent_Changes_semanage_fcontext) later.

   Or
2. Allow the web server to read files in home directories by setting the [appropriate](https://serverfault.com/a/461526/126632) SELinux [boolean](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/SELinux_Users_and_Administrators_Guide/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-Booleans.html):

   ```
   setsebool -P httpd_read_user_content 1
   ```

   Note that it is never allowed for the web server to *write* to home directories, so if you need to write to the filesystem, see the other option.

Comment: Weird, even with `setenforce 0` I get the same error.