# Virtual hosts not working in Fedora 22

Tags: centos, virtualhost, apache-2.4, fedora

Recently I've switched from Ubuntu to Fedora Workstation as my development enviroment to better understand centOS servers (and for other reasons too).

I've been trying to set up a local LAMP stack for developement.

**Here is what I have atm**:

```
httpd    Apache/2.4.16 (Fedora), runs as apache/apache,
         mod_php is disabled,
         handler is
         "proxy:unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock|fcgi://localhost"

php      5.6.14

php-fpm  runs as apache/apache,
         path is /run/php-fpm/www.sock, process type is mpm_event
```

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf**

```
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

I haven't really rouched any of the settings in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`.
The server and PHP seems to work fine for `/var/www/html`, but when I try to create a new `VirtualHost`, I get `403` for all directories. I am trying to a new vhost by adding a config file:

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/sites.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site1.local
    ServerAlias site1alias.local
    DocumentRoot /home/myuser/Projects/site1/www
    <Directory /home/myuser/Projects/site1/www>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**httpd -S**

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's
fully qualified domain name, using ::1.
Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   site1.local (/etc/httpd/conf.d/sites.conf:4)
ServerRoot: "/etc/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/etc/httpd/logs/error_log"
Mutex default: dir="/run/httpd/" mechanism=default 
Mutex authdigest-opaque: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-client: using_defaults
Mutex lua-ivm-shm: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex authn-socache: using_defaults
PidFile: "/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="apache" id=48
Group: name="apache" id=48
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost gpc local localhost.localdomain site1.local site1alias.local
::1         localhost gpc local localhost.localdomain
```

**SELinux** is set to 'permissive' by using `setenforce 0` (seems to be showing warnings but permits the actions).

Whenever I try to browse `http://localhost/` or `http://site1.local/`, I get

`Forbidden: You don't have permission to access / on this server.`

Perhaps the

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's
fully qualified domain name, using ::1.
Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

has something to do with this? I've tried chaning `ServerName localhost` directive in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` but it had no effect. I'm running out of ideas heres. I feel like I'm missing something in the configuration. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**:

Entries from `/var/log/httpd/error_log`:

```
[Sat Oct 31 17:29:33.253428 2015] [core:notice] [pid 844:tid 140376890374272] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Sat Oct 31 17:29:33.259649 2015] [suexec:notice] [pid 844:tid 140376890374272] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using ::1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Sat Oct 31 17:29:33.274149 2015] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 844:tid 140376890374272] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Oct 31 17:29:33.275309 2015] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 844:tid 140376890374272] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sat Oct 31 17:29:33.279406 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 844:tid 140376890374272] AH00489: Apache/2.4.16 (Fedora) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Oct 31 17:29:33.279437 2015] [core:notice] [pid 844:tid 140376890374272] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sat Oct 31 17:30:18.500583 2015] [core:error] [pid 937:tid 140376476202752] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:42036] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/myuser/Projects') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
[Sat Oct 31 17:30:18.667997 2015] [core:error] [pid 937:tid 140376459417344] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:42036] AH00035: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/home/myuser/Projects') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path, referer: http://site1.local/
```

**Permissions**

```
apache/apache 755 /var/www/html/
apache/apache 755 /home/myuser/Projects/site1/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your error. Look carefully:

```
[Sat Oct 31 17:30:18.500583 2015] [core:error] [pid 937:tid 140376476202752] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:42036] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/myuser/Projects') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
[Sat Oct 31 17:30:18.667997 2015] [core:error] [pid 937:tid 140376459417344] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:42036] AH00035: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/home/myuser/Projects') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path, referer: http://site1.local/
```

This is happening because Apache doesn't have permission to *search* (descend, the `x` permission) one of the parent directories.

To resolve the problem, first check to see which parent directory is missing the proper permissions, e.g. with `namei -l /home/myuser/Projects/index.php`. Find the directory that is missing the `x` permissions for all users, and give the correct permissions with `chmod a+x /directory`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The apache process must be able to read all folders leading up to the actual `DocumentRoot`. Another problem was SELinux, which was getting in the way of apache reading the files. The two issues completely colved the problem.

Comment: See [here](http://serverfault.com/a/461526/126632) regarding SELinux.

Answer (score 1):

The error could not qualify fqdn has nothing to do with it, you can fix that by adding an entry to /etc/hosts with your external ip and then the hostname. Regarding the php error: anything in the logs of apache?

EDIT:

Please check the permissions of /home/myuser/Projects it has to be readable for the httpd user apache (at least r-x)

Comment: What php error? The request doesn't even hit php files. P.S. I added apache errors.

Comment: The error forbidden, could also have come from an php error, but in your case it looks like an apache issue

Comment: permissions are ok